# Old version of my app builds rather than latest in react native ios build

Tags: ios, build, native

React Native building the older version of the project for ios build when building from Xcode even after pulling the latest code from gitlab.
Also Reload is not Working in simulator, just showing the previous build.

Latest Code is there in the project and also showing no errors in the xcode.

Making the build from .xcWorkspace file.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with 'react-native run-ios'?

Comment: Hi, did you fix it? I'm facing with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the way I fixed was by running the same command that is usually recommended to bundle the app again:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/{APP_NAME}/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

With the only minor difference being that I had to direct the generated `main.jsbundle` to the folder named after my app inside the ios folder, and not just the ios folder itself.

It seems at some point the place where the project looks for the file got changed, so without rebundling to the new location it kept loading the old file. You should check that your project is copying the assets and the bundle from the right location.

The `index.ios.js` entry file is also specific to this project having one for each platform. Normally you would use `index.js`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue. It was because I had run `xcode-select` in an older versions of the app. After I ran it in the new version, everything worked.

Not entirely sure if it's the same issue you had, but maybe this will help someone out there.